# Event tracking not working for 1 link but all other work without onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Ive got a client that I've just taken on.. They are wanting to track external links using event tracking.

Im using universal analytics and I've followed all the documentation from google.

This is in my header php.

```
`<script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

and I've edited my link

```
`<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>`
```

But it doesn't save the onclick code when I update the page and its not showing up in real time reporting.

It did work for 1 day using this code

```
`onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'Click', 'Ebook downloaded', '0');" href="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/free-ebook.pdf">Download Free Ebook</a>`
```

after I setup a goal but then stopped working.

All of the other events are being tracked in analytics but they don't appear to have any code inside the links at all but they are all internal.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't offer you a solution to your specific problem, I can share with you another (and IMHO easier) solution to accomplish file download tracking since I recently implemented this on my site.

Instead of hard coding events into every page so they fire on a button click using javascript's onclick (your example), I used  Google Tag Manager (GTM) Auto Event Tracking to listen for clicks on a link, and then fire an event on the click and return the link's label as the event label.

The best part of this method is you don't have to customize any link on any page--GTM does it for you. You can create a trigger to fire the event based on one or more file types (PDF, etc), a single file, or depending on the fidelity required in your reporting, you can also create multiple triggers for different files or file types.

Once implemented, the file download data can be found in the **Reporting > Behaviors > Events** section of Google Analytics as expected.

The article by seoWorks (with whom I'm not affiliated) at the link below details it better than I could in this forum, and contains step-by-step instructions with screenshots.
https://www.seoworks.com/01-seo-news-views/track-file-downloads-in-google-analytics-using-gtm/.

Hope this helps.